# How to extract and copy text after a keyword from text file in terminal

Tags: shell, text, grep

I have a text file which I want to scan for a keyword like "Day 17" and copy the text after that keyword.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` used with `tail` would achieve the result you want and here's how:

1. https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ugrep.htm#syntax
2. https://www.computerhope.com/unix/utail.htm

`$ grep -A 650 "Day 17" anytextfilehere.txt | tail -n + 2 > resultOfOutput.txt`

The first part of the command will look for the pattern `Day 17` within the file `anytextfilehere.txt` and print at and after the keyword with every successive lines after it, because of the Context line control `-A` being used.

The second part of the command with `tail` will specify to not include the line where the pattern `Day 17` was found into the output result itself. The result of this output is sent into `resultOfOutput.txt`

If your file is too big for the value you have setted at the Context line control then increase it.